# Yii2: subquery in Oracle (oci) format

Tags: yii2, subquery, oracle-call-interface

I currently have a model which is connected to an oracle database. It is working well and I am able to execute queries without a problem.

However, the following causes the oracle database to reject the query:

```
    $subquery = mytable::find()->where(['status'=>'success']);

    $mainQuery = new Query(); 
    $mainQuery->select([...])
    ->from(['subQ'=>$subquery])
    ->where(...
```

In the example above, the $subquery runs fine (if I run it by itself) but the combination is rejected by the Oracle database

I think the issue is that "new Query()" invokes a mysql query not an oci query. How do I instantiate the Query() as an oci query?

Any help appreciated.

### Example

I have created the following simple query to demonstrate the issue:

```
$subQuery = Study::find()->limit(10);
$mainQuery = new Query;
$mainQuery->select(["*"])->from(['subQ'=>$subQuery]);
```

The Study class is configured to call the Oracle database.

When the query above is executed, I receive the following message from the Oracle db:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'username'@'db.url' for table 'study'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `SCHEMA`.`STUDY` LIMIT 10) `subQ`
```

If I execute $subQuery alone, all is fine and 10 records are returned. I am not an expert in Oracle queries but it looks to me like the query being rejected is using the MySQl syntax and not an oracle syntax. This implies that the new Query class is overriding the Study query.

How do I force the new Query to use the oci syntax?

Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "*is rejected by the Oracle database*"?

Comment: @rob006 many thanks - I have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to instruct the Query to connect to the desired database as follows:

```
$qry = new Query();
$qry-> // usual commands
$qry->all(Yii::$app->dbName);
```

This works well.